# How to remove init script from docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

New to docker and this probably a simple question. I've searched around and can't find anything to help.

I have the following simple Dockerfile.

```
FROM postgres

COPY *.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

I have one init.sh, that it copies and runs on init. I have removed this file from the project but it still gets ran everytime I start the container.

How do I actually remove the file from the startup process?

Comment: did you rebuild the image?